# Why does static var syntax sometimes throw an error and sometimes not

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am very confused, in different projects I can sometimes write

```
class Foo {
  static BAR = {
    foobar: 'baz'
  }
}
```

And sometimes this cannot be compiled and instead I have to write

```
class Foo {
  static get BAR() {
    return {
      foobar: 'baz'
    }
  }
}
```

I really don't like the second syntax, the first one is much more concise. The problem is that the first syntax works in one project and in another project it throws a syntax error and I don't know why.

It seems using different Babel presets has an effect. Do different ECMAScript versions have different definitions on this?

Comment: Your two definitions do not do exactly the same thing.  In the first, you can do `Foo.BAR.foobar = 'whatever'`, but in the second, it is only a getter, it does not store a value you set.

Comment: The first snippet is using a [Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/). It's not part of of any standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that one is a static [*class property*](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) while the other is a [*static method*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static), a getter to be specific. Class properties are part of Babel's [`stage-2` preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/)<sup>1</sup>. Per the link:

> **Stage 2:** draft
>
> **What is it?** A first version of what will be in the specification. At this point, an eventual inclusion of the feature in the standard is likely.

Thus, class properties are not a part of ECMAScript yet, but likely will be in the specification in the future in a later version, ECMAScript 2016. On the other hand, static methods are already a part of the ECMAScript 2015 specification, so browsers that support ECMAScript 2015 already allow you to do this.

---

<sup>1</sup> The certain stages of presets are described [here](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets-stage-x-experimental-presets-) and describe the stage of development a certain feature is in.